# How to add general title to angular material stepper (in the same line of the steppers)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat stepper, to implement an workflow.
I want to add some text (header) to the stepper component,
and the text should appear in the same row of the stepper.
I tried to add a div/ span insinde the mat-stepper but it is not even display

the expected result is something like this:
[image: title]

Answer (score 0):

You can use matStepLabel directive of mat-stepper like this:

```
<mat-stepper orientation="vertical" [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
      // your code
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i want the title to be on the right side of the screen (look at the attached img) with your solution its appear bellow the steppers.may you have another idae?